# External HDD works on WIn8 but not on 14.04

Tags: external-hdd

I have a 1TB Dell HDD, about a year old. On attaching it to my 14.04 machine (near fresh install), the system mounts the drive, but is unable to browse it (nautilus hangs, as does the terminal if I try to cd into /media/X/HDD, as does fdisk -l). Almost every time, the system shuts down all running processes and logs me out after some time.

I put the drive on my friend's windows machine, where chkdsk found a few issues. After repair, the drive works perfectly on the windows machine, but similar behaviour persists on ubuntu, with the fresh dressing of a couple of kernel panics on trying to eject/remove it.

Is there any way to make the drive work on my machine, or should I back it up and format it?

Comment: do you have ntfs-config, libntfs-dev, libntfs10, and ntfsprogs installed? run the command: `dpkg -l | grep ntfs` to list what is installed.

Comment: Also, run the command `dmesg | tail` and pleas post any related errors listed.

Comment: How is the disk partitioned and formatted? If it has Linux partitions, are they freshly fsck'd?

Comment: Finally, if you run gparted and select the drive, there should be error messages and it should even have instructions for you on how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must be aware that Win8 doesn't power off; it hibernates for a faster boot, keeping HD mounted and occupied so linux can't mount it. Althought as you said, linux mount the drive, I think would worth check if this option is deactivated -so windows shuts down properly and sets the drive free.

Here's a [link](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/12/disable-hybrid-boot-windows-8/) where the author explains how to deactivate this feature